# Add unchanged open file to Working Files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is there a way to add a file opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to Working Files?

The documentation lists three ways to add a file to Working Files. The only one for an unchanged file that's in the currently opened folder involves manually selecting and double-clicking the file, which I'd rather avoid.

> - make a change to a file
> - double-click a file in the Explorer
> - open a file that is not part of the current folder

(https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> adds the current file to Working Files.

Found by remembering to try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and searching for *Working Files*.

Comment: Is there a way to make it default behaviour